# reactjs animations - using CSS only transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions, reactjs

Can some one point me to a simple example using CSS transitions no other libraries in reactjs to animate image from negative to positive right/left positions on component load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for

```
.example-enter {
  opacity: 0.01;
  position: relative;
  left: -100px
}

.example-enter.example-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

Component

```
class Container extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        items: [0],
      counter: 0
    };
    this.handleAdd = this.handleAdd.bind(this);
  }
    handleAdd(){
    const counter = this.state.counter + 1,
        items = this.state.items.concat([counter]);

    this.setState({
        counter,items
    })
  }
  render(){
    const items = this.state.items.map(item => {
        return <li className='example' key={item}>{item}</li>
    })
    return <ul className='container'>
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
          transitionName="example"
          transitionEnterTimeout={500}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={300}>
          {items}
        </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
      <hr/>
      <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>New One</button>
    </ul>
  }


}
React.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

And also link to `>>` [`React Animation`](https://jsfiddle.net/g5bcg74q/59/) & worked [`fiddle`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

Thanks